# How to load the data from database to table in Java Fx mysql

Tags: java, javafx

I am a beginner of java fx I made a simple crud operation on javafx. I did add the records into the database. I want view the records from database table what I tried so far I attached below. My problem is I couldn't set the values into relevant table columns.

```
 @FXML
    
    private TableView<Record> table;
    
    @FXML
    private TableColumn<?, ?> tabl1;

    @FXML
    private Button btnAdd;

    @FXML
    private Button btnUpdate;

    @FXML
    private Button btnDelete;

    @FXML
    private Button btnClear;
    
    @FXML
    private TableColumn<?, ?> idColumn;

    @FXML
    private TableColumn<?, ?> booknameColumn;

    @FXML
    private TableColumn<?, ?> priceColumn;

    @FXML
    private TableColumn<?, ?> EditionColumn;

  Connection con;
    PreparedStatement pst;

      public void table()
      {
          Connect();
          ObservableList<Record> records = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
       try 
       {
           pst = con.prepareStatement("select id,bookname,price,edition from books");  
           ResultSet rs = pst.executeQuery();
    {
        while (rs.next())
        {
            Record record = new Record();
            record.setId(rs.getString("id"));
            record.setBname(rs.getString("bookname"));
            record.setPrice(rs.getString("price"));
            record.setEdition(rs.getString("edition"));
            records.add(record);
        }
    } 
 
      table.setItems(records);
      idColumn.setCellValueFactory(f -> f.getValue.);
      booknameColumn.setCellValueFactory(f -> f.getValue().);
      priceColumn.setCellValueFactory(f -> f.getValue());  
       }
       catch (SQLException ex) 
       {
           Logger.getLogger(FXMLDocumentController.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
       }

        

}
```

i created class Record.java

```
public class Record {
    
     String id;
     String bname;
   String price;
    String edition;

    public Record() {
    }

    public Record(String id, String bname, String price, String edition) {
        this.id = id;
        this.bname = bname;
        this.price = price;
        this.edition = edition;
    }

    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getBname() {
        return bname;
    }

    public void setBname(String bname) {
        this.bname = bname;
    }

    public String getPrice() {
        return price;
    }

    public void setPrice(String price) {
        this.price = price;
    }

    public String getEdition() {
        return edition;
    }

    public void setEdition(String edition) {
        this.edition = edition;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Record{" + "id=" + id + ", bname=" + bname + ", price=" + price + ", edition=" + edition + '}';
    }
```

I don't know why I couldn't set the values here

```
  idColumn.setCellValueFactory(f -> f.getValue.); **not show id**
  booknameColumn.setCellValueFactory(f -> f.getValue().);  **not bookname show id**
  priceColumn.setCellValueFactory(f -> f.getValue());   **not priceshow id**
```

Comment: [mcve] please .. mind the __M__ and make sure the code compiles

Comment: See if you can get some ideas from https://github.com/sedj601/SQLitePersonTableViewExample